# How to design a matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, constructor

I wanted to design a matrix and wanted that it is not possible to initialize it bad. Consider for example this:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int R, unsigned int C>
class matrix {
  array<T,R*C> _data;

  //... Constructors, etc. ...
};
```

Now I would like to have a design where the following is possible or even not:

```
auto mat1 = matrix<int,2,2>{1, 2, 3, 4};
auto mat2 = matrix<int,2,2>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // Error! Hopefully at compile time
auto mat3 = matrix{1,2,3,4}; // matrix<int,2,2>
```

Is there a elegant way to express that? With Constructors and initializer_list? Is it possible to check the size of provided arguments?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but, you can have a look at eigen libraries: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Instead `array<T,R*C>` it is more handy to have `array<array<T, R>, C>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a constructor taking an arbitrary amount of arguments + a deduction guide to calculate the sizes:

```cpp
template <class T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
struct matrix {
    // take anything and forward it:
    template <class... Args>
    matrix(Args&&... args) : _data{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {
        // assert that the sizes are correct:
        static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == R * C, "invalid init");
    }

    std::array<T, R * C> _data;
};

// integer square root
template<std::size_t T, std::size_t N = 0>
constexpr std::size_t isqrt() {
    if constexpr ((N+1) * (N+1) <= T) return isqrt<T, N + 1>();
    return N;
}

// Deduction guide:
template <class T, class... Args>
matrix(T&&, Args&&...) ->
    matrix<T, isqrt<sizeof...(Args) + 1>(), isqrt<sizeof...(Args) + 1>()>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/91de1szeE)